# How to submit a form with a checkbox?

Tags: java, jsf, checkbox, javabeans

Is it possible to submit a JSF form with the help of a checkbox?

I have multiple checkboxes and when I click on one of them, then it should actually submit the form and go to the next page. The checkbox value should be bound to a backing bean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With JSF 1.x you can do:

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{aBean.aFiled}" onclick="submit()" />
```

If you use JSF 2.x, then you can use ajax:

```html
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{aBean.aFiled}">
  <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

For JSF and ajax take a look at: [Learning JSF2: Ajax in JSF – using f:ajax tag](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/)

Comment: okay, it takes the value of the bean.. but the question remains partly unanswered.
I need to pass the checkbox value to a query and display a chart using xml.. so i need to completely reload another page.
Any better idea is welcomed.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406855/jsf-navigation-with-ajax) there is a discussion about ajax and navigation.
I think, you can't do a page navigation.
you could try to put the graph on the same page, render it only upon check box selection and at the same time you hide the form.